# Summing the values of an integer array in BigQuery using javascript UDF

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this where `coord1` is a repeated integer field:

[image]

Now, I try to calculate the sum of that integer array `coord1` in BigQuery using the following code. After running this code, surprisingly, I get a string concatenation of the values in that array. Here is my code and output:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION func(array_values ARRAY<INT64>)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var divisor = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < array_values.length; i++){
    divisor = divisor + array_values[i];
  };
  return divisor;
""";

with
  `project.dataset.table` as
  (
    SELECT 1 id1, [1, 2, 3, 4] coord1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1]
  )
SELECT
  id1,
  coord1,
  func(coord1) as array_sum
from
 `project.dataset.table`
```

[image]

But when I add a `parseInt` function before adding the values in the array it seems to be adding up the numbers properly in that array:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION func(array_values ARRAY<INT64>)
RETURNS INT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var divisor = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < array_values.length; i++){
    divisor = divisor + parseInt(array_values[i]);
  };
  return divisor;
""";

with
  `project.dataset.table` as
  (
    SELECT 1 id1, [1, 2, 3, 4] coord1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, [2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1]
  )
SELECT
  id1,
  coord1,
  func(coord1) as array_sum
from
 `project.dataset.table`
```

[image]

I don't understand what I was doing wrong in the first code I posted which results in the values in the array to be treated as string and returns me the concatenation of those strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#sql-type-encodings-in-javascript):

> Because JavaScript does not support a 64-bit integer type, `INT64` is unsupported as an input type for JavaScript UDFs. Instead, use `FLOAT64` to represent integer values as a number, or `STRING` to represent integer values as a string.

Even though the type is not officially supported, BigQuery uses an encoding of JavaScript's String type to represent `INT64` in order not to lose precision if you just want to pass through values of that type. If you want to convert to Number, though, you should use `parseInt`.